# Mysqli Select query not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
$sql = "select company_name, salary, experience from company";
echo $sql;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

output

```
select company_name, salary, experience from company
Array ( [0] => xyz [company_name] => xyz [1] => 2 Lac - 3 Lac [salary] => 2 Lac - 3 Lac [2] => 2 Years - 3 Years [experience] => 2 Years - 3 Years )
```

In this code I have a table name company where I have multiple rows but when I execute this query it show me only first row data only I don't know why and Where I am doing wrong? How can I fix this issue ?

Thank You

Comment: try like this while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the row number in your **while loop**; `row[0]`, `row[1]`

Comment: I would be interested in a fuller explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array

```
$res = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $res[] = $row;
}

print_r($res); exit;
```